# DJI UX SDK No Message about Register success or Not

Tags: dji-sdk

I have successfully installed the UX SDK demo on my Android device from GitHub, but I don't get a message whether the registration was successful or not.  I have added the appropriate app key to the packages.  There are no bars in the app display for wifi, maybe the app is not connected to the internet?  How can I find out or change that? The device is connected.
Otherwise, what could be the problem with the registration?

Thank you in advcance!

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake.  I didn't run the UX SDK Sample App but a tutorial.  Therefore it was not shown.

Comment: I think to experience the same thing. Running the UXSDKDemo. I do see this line in de the debugger hit: `DJISDKManager.getInstance().registerApp(getApplicationContext(), mDJISDKManagerCallback);` but what is inside the callback passed on, is never called back. So no 'Register success' or 'Register Failed'. What do you mean with that you ran the tutorial and not the sample app?